# Turbogears 2 / Pylons

Tags: pylons, turbogears2

I am really confused i have a directory structure as follows.
/foo/bar/project/

under project is the python environment via virtualenv.

I have two additional folders live, and beta.

Live is served via apache wsgi and beta is served using paster.

Some how the live site is serving templates from the beta directory. To make sure i wasn't losing my mind I renamed the beta directory to wtfbeta expecting the server to throw an error helping me track down what went wrong.

Nope, instead it just falls back to loading the correct template from the live directory. (after service apache2 restart).

I am really stuck here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was related to both sites using the same virtualenv.